# Why doesn't putting a magnet in a coil create a current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, maxwell-equations

According to Amperes law the integral of the magnetic field $B$ dotted with the $dl$ along a closed loop is proportional to the current passing through the surface area of any shape given by the closed loop path, so my question is why doesn't a magnet stationary in a coil continuously create a current, this seems to go against what you would get by solving Amperes equation

Comment: What closed path are you considering?

Comment: One that follows the magnetic field lines through and around a solenoid

Comment: I would suggest: "why doesn't a magnet stationary in a coil continuously create a current". Putting a magnet into a coil in the first place does induce a current, since you have to move the magnet relative to the coil to get it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral form of the Ampere-Maxwell equation is:

$$ \oint_c b \cdot dl = \mu_0 \left( I_{enc} + \epsilon_0 \frac{d}{dt} \int_s e \cdot \hat n \ \ da \right) $$

Here the Current enclosed term  $I_{enc}$ can be written as the integral of current densities.
$$ I_{enc} = \int_s  
\left(
\mathbf j_f + \frac{\partial \mathbf p}{\partial t} + \Delta \times \mathbf m
\right) \cdot d \mathbf a
$$

The three current densities are:

1. $\mathbf j_f$ from the movement of free charges.
2. $\mathbf j_p = \frac{\partial \mathbf p}{\partial t}$  is the contribution to current from polarization.
3. $\mathbf j_m = \Delta \times \mathbf m $ is the magnetization current.

Yes, the contour integral on the left side of the Ampere-Maxwell equation for the loop you are considering is non-zero. But the term that accounts for this on the right hand side of the equation is the magnetization current caused due to the permanent magnetic dipoles present in the magnet and not an electric current in the solenoid.